# Comparing means for 2 sets of (paired?) data

Tags: regression, t-test, linear-model

N patients with N samples from site A and N from site B (before and after treatment). In both sites we find 1-4 microbes, which are tested for antimicrobial susceptibility to obtain MIC values.

I wish to determine if the mean-MIC in site-A samples are actually lower than the mean-MIC in site-B.

Which model to choose, when I need to include at least 3 covariates  age, (sex), drug and duration and uncertain if the data is actually paired??

I would go for a 2-sample paired t-test - but how will can I integrate 3 covariates?

Please consider also, that in most cases the microbe in site A is the same as in site B - but in 10-15 % of the cases we have different microbes (and also different numbers). So, would it be inappropriate to pool all the data and compare the overall means? Or should I divide the data so I separately consider the groups with identical microbes and the groups with various microbes?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have missing data and that you have repeated measures (and that the assumption of sphericity is unlikely to be reasonable). I suggest a multi-level model. In `R` see `lme4` or `nlme` packages. In `SAS` look at `PROC MIXED`.

Comment: Now I understand the assumption of sphericity and yes, that would be a mistake to do. But what is my missing data? And the repeated measure is not quite right, as but group A **is** before and group B **is** after treatment. So A and B differs in both time AND condition, which is the reason I doubted that the data is paired in the first place.

Comment: Your missing data is the lack of repetition.

Answer (score 0):

So you have group A and group B, and you have a before and after measurement. This means that you have both *time* and *condition*, so a two-way repeated measure ANOVA is in place.

Any covariates can be included in this kind of analysis.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Repeated measures ANOVA does not deal well with  missing data and assumes sphericity. It is not a good choice here.

Comment: Thank you for both responses!! @Peter Flom However, I do not understand the assumption of sphericity nor the missing data (which is?). I expect normally distributed values for the MIC-measurements. Moreover, sorry for the confusion - but group A is before, while group B is after treatment. So A and B differs in both time AND condition, which is the reason I doubt paired data.